# How to setup DGRAM socket in C

Tags: c

My server connects successfully, but I am not seeing any message from client/server in my terminal whenever I use `SOCK_DGRAM`. Am I missing any functions for this type of socket? The code below works fine with `SOCK_STREAM` with this I also have one small problem, I am not seeing message from client in my server terminal but I do see "Connected to server" in client terminal. Can someone advise?

Client

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {

  int socket_server;
  int socket_connect;
  int socket_listen;
  char buffer[256];
  char sendMsg[256] = "Received from client";

  struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
  socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  socket_address.sin_port = htons(4003);
  socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  socket_connect= connect(socket_server, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
  socket_listen = listen(socket_server, 5);

  recv(socket_server, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
  send(socket_server, &sendMsg, sizeof(sendMsg), 0);
  printf("%s", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Server

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {

  int socket_server;
  int socket_bind;
  int socket_listen;
  char buffer[256] = "Connected to server";
  char fromClient[256];

  struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
  socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  socket_address.sin_port = htons(4003);
  socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  socket_bind = bind(socket_server, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
  socket_listen = listen(socket_server, 5);

  for(;;) {
    int socket_accept = accept(socket_server, NULL, NULL);
    send(socket_accept, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    recv(socket_accept, &fromClient, sizeof(fromClient), 0);
    printf("%s", fromClient);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `accept` (or `listen`, and often not `connect`) with a UDP socket. You need to rewrite your server to rely only on `send` and `recv` (or `sendto`/`recvfrom`). See e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-client-server-using-connect-c-implementation/.

Answer (score 1):

UDP sockets don't use `listen` or `accept`.
Messages from all clients are received on the original socket to which you bound the address.  The `connect` is not really establishing a connection, it is just saving the remote address so that it knows where to send each datagram when using `send` (as opposed to `sendto`).

It also looks odd that the client expects the first message to come from the server, probably because you expected the server to detect the `connect`, which it does not.  Normally the server would be up and running and send responses to requests, so the client needs to send a request and then wait for a response, and the server needs to wait for a request and then send a response.  The server will need to use `recvfrom` so that it knows where to send the response!

Comment: Also, be aware that UDP is not reliable, so the request may be lost before the server sees it, and the response may be lost before the client sees it

Comment: Incidentally, if dgram sockets were connection oriented, and required `listen` and `accept`, your code would be leaking descriptors since you don't  close the `socket_accept` at the end of the loop.  I mention this in case you intend to move to TCP.

Comment: In production code, you need to check the return values for errors, and not send unvetted data received from the network directly to `printf`!

Comment: You are also echoing the entire buffer, and not just the amount of data actually received.  This is sending uninitialized data over the network!